# Summing all Instance of Variable in Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Sub yeartest()
Dim cell As Range
storeval = 0
For Each cell In Range("I7:I17")
If cell.Value = "THISVALUE" Then

Let storeval = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value


End If

Range("Q18").Activate
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(storeval)"
Next cell
End Sub
```

What the code should do is analyze the range I7:I17. Everytime it encounters a cell in this range with the value THISVALUE it should go right by one cell and store that value. After the entire range has been analyzed the sum of all cells one right of THISVALUE should be output in cell Q18.

Currently cell Q18 just displays a #NONAME value when I execute the macro.

Comment: You are trying to sum the value directly above `"THISVALUE"`?

Comment: Plus `storeval` is just one value, why sum it at all: `Range("Q18").Value = storeval`  also you do not need the `Let`

Comment: And this can be done with a formula: `=SUMIF(I7:I17,"THISVALUE",I6:I16)`

Comment: @Scott Craner, see my edit for for clarification.

Comment: okay then you are using offset wrong, it is (row,column).  But a simple SUMIF will work: `=SUMIF(I7:I17,"THISVALUE",J7:J17`

Comment: If you must use vba then change the Offset in the answer below to `(0,1)`

Comment: Great, that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub yeartest()
   Dim cll As Range
   storeval = 0
   For Each cll In Range("I7:I17")
       If cell.Value = "THISVALUE" Then
           storeval = storeval + cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
       End If
   Next cll
   Range("Q18")=storeval
End Sub
```

Comment: add explanation of your code which helpful to OP and future readers.